# Android: application doesn't display the progress bar at the start

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask

When my Application starts, It does a lot of scanning; traversing through the root folder to find some particular folders and then it scans for video files. The problem is that I get a blank screen for approximately 4 to 5 seconds at the start of the application. I wanted to display progress bar but it seems that the application doesn't wait for the progress bar to appear; rather it continues going into the time-consuming traversing loops and after that it displays the progress bar.. Can someone give an example or a suggestion.. I have an idea that AsynTask may help here but I am looking for a certain example..

Thanks all.

Comment: Adding some code could be useful what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private class xyz extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(tranning.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        this.dialog.show();
        // put your code which preload with processDialog  
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // put your code here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
          this.dialog.dismiss();

        }   
    }
}
```

**and use this in main  ::**

```
new xyz().execute();
```

Comment: Sir, what if I want to do some more operations in the main function after the processing inside (doInBackground) is finished.. I just want to wait in the main function while the (doInBackground) is working.. Is there any way?

Comment: Farhan, you don't want to do that! That would involve blocking the UI thread, causing issues such as the one you describe (the progress dialog not appearing). You could try sending a `Message` to a `Handler` when the traverse operation is complete, to trigger of the next operation you want to do, or even simply calling `yourFunc()` from `onPostExecute` if you want it to run on the UI thread.

Comment: Sir, one last question.. Can you just tell me that how long the AsynTask remains active.. I mean, does the thread ends after onPostExecute or is it still running along with the UI thread.. Your answer helped me in showing the progress bar initially.. Thanks alot.. Please clarify the question that I have asked in this message..

Comment: Thank you Sir. One more question please. Can we use more than one AsynTask based class in a single application?

Comment: ya you can use multiple class in single activity and make multiple process at background

Answer (score 0):

Put the code which displays the progress bar in the onCreate() method above all traversing code and then try it may be it helps you.

Comment: no, it doesn't help.. the application doesn't wait for the progress bar to be displayed. It rather goes into the traversing and get stuck in there..